# capture image in raw format

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image

I want to capture a picture in raw format. I found this post with the parameters, which i should set.
[How to capture raw image from android camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777953/how-to-capture-raw-image-from-android-camera)

I used this code to find the parameters, which are available for my device:
[How to get Camera RAW metadata info programmatically Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680071/how-to-get-camera-raw-metadata-info-programmatically-android)
but the only paremter, which includes the String "raw" is this one

```
picture-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv420p,yuv422i-yuyv,rgb565,raw,jpeg
```

when i call this method

```
mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureFormats()
```

i get his values

```
[17, 842094169, 20, 4, 256]
```

so in the documentation it says nothing about raw format
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html

the `data` of my  `Camera.PictureCallback raw` is also empty

Is it possible for me to capture pictures in raw format ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture raw image from android camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777953/how-to-capture-raw-image-from-android-camera)